# Docker and nested Volumes

Tags: docker

I am trying to dockerize a web-application. It requires PHP, thus I use `richarvey/nginx-php-fpm`.

As the web-app stores configuration data into the web-root, the web-root must be persistent. Thus, I opted to create a volume for the web-root:

```
./smartvisu/Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER abc
RUN apt-get -y install git


RUN commands to get data into /usr/share/nginx/html
VOLUME /usr/share/nginx/html
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/tail -f /dev/null
```

This works well. The Data is persistent.
Unfortunately though I need to let the user of the docker-image inject two folders into the webroot:
`/usr/share/nginx/html/lib`, `/usr/share/nginx/html/pages/mypages`.

So, what I tried is:

```
smartvisu_data:
  build: ./smartvisu/.

smartvisu:
  image: richarvey/nginx-php-fpm
  volumes_from:
  - smartvisu_data
  volumes:
  - /mnt2/RockOn_Configs/config/smartvisuconfig/lib:/usr/share/nginx/html/lib
  - /mnt2/RockOn_Configs/config/smartvisuconfig/pages/henfri/:/usr/share/nginx/html/pages/henfri
  ports:
  - 8080:80
```

Now, unfortunately, the `volumes_from` part does work, but mounting the two folders on top of /into the folder does not work.

The folders `/usr/share/nginx/html/lib`
and 
`/usr/share/nginx/html/pages/henfri` are empty.

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure about your file permissions. Your host folder must has rw permission by docker user.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer to the question.

Comment: I think he has a permission problem and thats a clear answer, maybe i could add command to change permission on linux. :)